# WCAT Problem

Tags: asp.net, iis, wcat

I am trying to stress test an ASP.Net MVC application using the WCAT tool. I get results when the WCAT client and controller are on the web server(localhost), but when I move the WCAT client to another machine, I get "404 Not found" errors. It seems that the WCAT client cannot make the http requests from the client machine even though if I type in the URL (on the client machine), I *can* access the website. This should rule out any firewall issues. What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue - when starting up the controller you must specify the server hostname (-a) and *not* "localhost".